# Jagged Array typed Properties

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, properties, jagged-arrays

Say I have a property like this:

```
public int[] MyProperty
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

The calling code is free to change the values of the array, *but also to replace the array itself*. This can easily be prevented by hiding the setter, like so:

```
public int[] MyProperty
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

This allows the calling code to change the values, but it can't change the array to a different one, or change the size.

This pattern works with multidimensional arrays, but not jagged arrays. If I have this:

```
public int[][] MyProperty
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

The main array can't be modified, but the child arrays can. What if I want to make the child arrays readonly, so that the calling code can change the elements, but not the arrays?

How can I make only the elements of jagged arrays modifiable? This includes 3D and higher.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [`ReadOnlyCollection<int[]>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx).

Comment: +1 very nice, could you elaborate just slightly to use it in a code example

Comment: Cool. Is there a way to solve the problem with jagged arrays?

Comment: @KendallFrey: No, there isn't.

Comment: Another question: I don't suppose there is anything wrong with `ReadOnlyCollection<Collection<int>>`? It seems more uniform, that's all.

Comment: @KendallFrey: That would actually be better.  Note, though, that clients will be able to `Add()` and `Remove()` from the inner collections.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that wouldn't work for me then. I guess I will still be using a jagged array behind the scenes, so I may end up doing a clone instead, just because it looks nasty to combine collections and arrays.