# Best way to expose a multidimensional array property as public?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I need to implement a multi dimensional array as a public property.
I used a jagged array for initial implementation as :

```
public int[][] ArrayProperty
{get; set;}
```

However, it gives me a code analysis error - 'CA1819:PropertiesShouldNotReturnArrays'

So I thought to change it to a nested List like :

```
public List<List<int>> ArrayProperty
{get;set;}
```

But I am pretty sure it will give another code analysis error saying to not nest generic types.
Also if I am changing it to List, I would prefer it to be read only, having a backup private field.

How can I update my property structure to have best implementation to suit my requirements?

Comment: Do you want the consumer to be able to edit the array?

Comment: Yes, he can get and set the values of array.

Comment: Well its only a warming, There is a really good reason why there is a warning, if however you know better you can disable it

Comment: I have found it easier in the past to maintain if you use a List/Array of a typed class rather than a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: The reason you are advised not to expose arrays is that they are mutable (unlike plain IEnumerable collections) and covariant, unlike Lists. However, if your design says you want to expose an array of arrays (which isn't really a multidimensional array), think hard "is that what I really want to do", and if so, suppress the warning and go for it.

Comment: Take a look at this one with  ReadOnlyCollection<int[]> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808098/jagged-array-typed-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Framework often solves this by creating a custom collection class. That way data can be validated, custom methods can be offered and the type name can make the code easier to understand.

```
class MyCollection : IList<int[]> { ... }
```

You could even go further and wrap the `int[]`:

```
//alterantively add an indexer instead of exposing the array
class MyThing { public int[] MyValues { get; set; } }

class MyCollection : IList<MyThing> { ... }
```

This can be a lot of work. If you are writing a library for others to consume this might be worth the effort. If it's internal code I'd just go with whatever is convenient. You can change it later because you are controlling all callers.

Comment: This looks like a good way to maintain code and provide flexibility in long run for exposed api. However current scope of my code is just until my project, hence will go with jagged array itself as it feels more suitable to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
2. Dictonary<string, Dictonary<string,string>>
```

Try using the above two.

Answer (score 0):

"Properties should not return arrays."

Microsoft documentation reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1819-properties-should-not-return-arrays?view=vs-2017)

Resolution is to implement custom getter.

> If you wish to allow the consumer of the class to modify a property, the following code shows a legal example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; 

namespace PerformanceLibrary
{    
    public class Book    
    {        
        private Collection<string> _Pages;         

        public Book(string[] pages)        
        {            
            _Pages = new Collection<string>(pages);        
        }         

        public Collection<string> Pages        
        {            
            get { return _Pages; }        
        }    
    }
}
```